# Is it possible to disable the Subscriber need for the acknowledgement message?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I will like to know if there is a way to disable the need from Google Pub/Sub to receive the acknowledgement message from a Subscriber when you push a specific message? If the message is somehow lost or not received by the subscriber configure Google PubSub to not send or try to send the same message avoiding duplicates. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, no. Without the acknowledgement, Cloud Pub/Sub couldn't guarantee at-least-once delivery, which is a core property of the service. One option is to always ack a message as soon as you receive it, even before processing it. However, this does mean you could lose a message if your subscriber restarts after acking it, but before processing it.

Comment: Kamal hi, thank you for your answer!!! when you mention "to always ack a message as soon as you receive it" you mean to akt the message inside the google pub/sub subscriber? Something like the subscriber auto confirm the message before sending it? If a couple of messages get lost It wont matter

Comment: I mean in the callback you pass to the subscriber client when instantiating it (assuming you are using one of the Pub/Sub client libraries). There is no auto ack feature in Cloud Pub/Sub, so you would make the first line of your message handler be an ack of the message you just received.

Comment: Thinking of another way, what you think if I configure:

1) The period of time when the Google Pub/Sub Subscriber try to re send a message that has not receive the acknowledge messages? As an example after 96 hours from the first attempt?

 2) In the same subscriber create a seek function that allow me to search and find messages that have not receive the acknowledgement messages after 48 hours and discharge or delete those messages?

Comment: Do you mean using retry policy to deliver a failed messages 96 hours later? That seems like an extreme amount of time to wait to try to redeliver the message. For 2, what do you mean by "create a seek function?" You mean use Pub/Sub's seek functionality?